# Wrong image size on device

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am making iOS app and created two image in photoshop. Background image (pic1) 2208x1242 px and second image (pic2) 928x195 px size.
When I run app on the device(iPhone 7 plus) in the landscape mode second image take almost half width of the device.

[image]
Second image placed programatically

```
// Constraints
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 195).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 928).isActive = true

    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

It seems that image is stretched in both directions. How to fix/avoid this issue?

1) Same issue after applying imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit 
[image]
2) If I replace this code

`imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 195).isActive = true
 imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 928).isActive = true`

with

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 928, height: 195)
```

then everything works, but I don't understand why the first version of the code (imageView.heightAnchor and imageView.widthAnchor) does not work?

Comment: Seems autolayout is wrong. Can you draw border line of `imageView` with `imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor` and `imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0`. You will see red line around imageView and check it is in the screen as expected.

Comment: `imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true` is not equivalent to `frame.x = 0`. Try `imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true`. If it fixes your issue, it means `view` size is not equal to `imageView`

Comment: 1) Here is the result: https://imgur.com/a/CQxnP 2) Issue is not with the image alignment but with the image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused the issue.

heightAnchor.constraint and widthAnchor.constraint use points as size measurement not pixels, and my image size 928x195 was in pixels. So to fix issue I just needed to divide my image size by 3 for @3x image.

From UIKit documentation:

NSLayoutDimension -
A factory class for creating size-based layout constraint objects using a fluent API.
Overview
Use these constraints to programatically define your layout using Auto Layout. All sizes are measured in POINTS.

Answer (score 2):

set image mode aspect fit

```
 imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help

Comment: Can you post it before and after applying the mode ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What should I post?

Comment: see remove the width and height constraints and give aspect ratio constraint of 928/195 , and width of device

Comment: this line of code imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 928, height: 195) fixed issue, but I don't understand why code with height\width anchor is not working

Comment: Did you set imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Yes, mageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to false

Comment: remove centerX constraint and put  **imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true**

Comment: did not help : https://imgur.com/a/mstas image is still stretched in both directions.